# Insert online shopping cart items into MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to insert a cart of items as a JSON object into a MongoDB collection using a mongoose schema.

The customer's ID is getting stored (which comes from the User DB), but the **cart items are not**. Here is my code:

Sample order data contained in local variable app.js called `cartData: { data:[] }`:

```
{
    data: [
      item {
        name: "Product Name 1",
        price: '2.99',
        sku: '13579',
        count: 8
      },
      item {
        name: 'Product Name 2',
        price: '21.99',
        sku: '24680',
        count: 2
      }
    ]
}
```

`Cart.js` (Cart Schema):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customerID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cartContents: {
        type: [Object]
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}, { collection: "ordersDB" })

const Cart = mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema)
module.exports = Cart
```

`app.js` (Order Submit Code):

```
const Cart = require("../models/Cart")
const customerID = req.user.customerID //Acquired from user database

const newOrder = new Cart({
    customerID,
    cartData
})
newOrder.save()
    .then(customer => {
        req.flash("successful", "Your order has been submitted!")
        res.redirect("/somepage")
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Result:

```
_id: abcd1234
> cart: Object
    > type: Array
        > <The Infinite Abyss Of Nothingness aka Empty>
customerID: "1234567890"
date: 2019-12-11T21:14:40.825+00:00
__v: 0
```

Any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on provided schema Mongoose expects you to pass a field called `cartContents`. Any other field not compatible with your schema will be ignored. To fix that just name your field explicitly:

```
const newOrder = new Cart({
    customerID,
    cartContents: cartData
})
```